# Can i use the gzip for windows mobile 6.5 application

Tags: php, apache, http, gzip

i need to use [gzip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm) like the [gzip Command in linux](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_gzip.htm) into a **windows mobile** application to compress data into a file and decompress it by gunzip in **php/apache/linux**,can i?? 
and does **C# mobile compact framework** support running a command,and i've searched for a cmd on the mobile device and i didn't found ??

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile will not contain a `gzip` executable. However, you likely can use `zlib`, specifically [zlib.NET](http://www.componentace.com/zlib_.NET.htm) to work on the compressed data - you will simply need to manually decode the gzip header.

Comment: well , i tried to do so but always there was a data error as i don't know the length of the gzip headers and actually i think that zlib is working with diff algorithms across languages